# os_username vs username in Oracle audits

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit

I have recently been given the task of building reports from the audits of our Oracle 11g database. While not being the DBA and him being on vacation for a few weeks I have troubles understanding how some informations are recorded.

My main concern is about the `os_username` and `username` field. When reading [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3056.htm#i1619732) I see that:

> os_username: Operating system login username of the user whose actions were audited
>
> username: Name (not ID number) of the user whose actions were audited.

In the audit_trail I found that `os_username` contained mostly login username which sure sounds like the definition but also contained entries by "oracle". While the obviously correct `os_username` had username of what seems to be our systems or things like OEM, the records with a `os_username` "oracle" all had username entries of login username making this confusing.

In the end, *what is the real difference between those 2 columns and on which should I base my query to know how many times a user was recorded?*

Any other references I could read on the subject would also be appreciated

Comment: os_username is the operating system account. username is the database account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os_username` is the name of the user that runs the application. The `username` is the name of the user defined in the database.

Suppose that `UserA` is logged on his desktop as `UserA` and runs an application to modify the data. When he is asked to connect he enters the credentials of `UserB`. In the audit you will find `UserA` as `os_username` and `UserB` as `username`.

This explains while you find `oracle` as `os_username` since this is the user that is used to run Oracle itself.